# Is there a more modern or more popular version of evms2?

Tags: storage

I've just re-discovered evms having forgotten about it years ago thinking it was overkill for my needs. To my disappointment it appears to be unmaintained and not very well supported anymore.

It seems like a very nice system and I'm wondering if there's a more recent  equivalent?

Comment: So what triggered your rediscovery? What was the special feature you needed?

Comment: I just liked the way that you can manage quite complex setups with what appears to be a pretty decent gui. It would be much quicker to use and I expect less prone to mistakes than reading up on all the LVM command line tools and going through the steps manually.

Comment: The most decent thing I`ve been working with is the Veritas Volume Manager. But that`s neither OpenSource nor free of charge...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Volume_Management_System)

> For a while, both LVM and EVMS were competing for inclusion in the mainline kernel. EVMS had more features and better userland tools, but the internals of LVM were more attractive to kernel developers, so in the end LVM won the battle for inclusion. In response, the EVMS team decided to concentrate on porting the EVMS userland tools to work with the LVM kernelspace.[(1)](http://lwn.net/Articles/14816/)
>
> Sometime after the release of version 2.5.5 on February 26, 2006, IBM discontinued development of the project. There have been no further releases. In 2008 Novell announced that the company would be moving from EVMS to LVM in future editions of their SuSE products,[(1)](http://lwn.net/Articles/14816/) while continuing to fully support customers using EVMS.
>
> [(1): short lwn.net article](http://lwn.net/Articles/14816/)

So it seems like `LVM2` is the more recent equivalent (although it might not be completely equivalent, I cannot say anything about that).

Comment: How embarrasing, the wikipedia page says it all!! What can I say, it was late at night. Yes I think LVM2 is what people use now, but I have to say the userland tools of evms are still way better by the looks of it!

Comment: LVM and EVMS aren't quite playing in the same field: LVM is a volume management interface and implementation for Linux; EVMS was that plus a unified interface to manage many volume types (disks, partitions, slices, LVM, EVMS, hardware and software RAID, and a few more). I don't know of anything else that's comparable to the management interface part of EVMS.

Comment: Just about that SuSE hint of the WiKi: in SLES 11 there is no EVMS any more. I personally never used it and never missed it.